# NodeJS - Is it possible to start a TCP and HTTP server in the same time?

Tags: node.js, sockets, http, tcp

Is it possible to start a tcp and http server together ?

Because it seem that I can't do that.
The http log is well printed but not the tcp server.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: An HTTP server *is* a TCP server. You already have dozens of TCP servers running in any given host. One or two more won't hurst.

Comment: @EJP (picky mode on) Well, I think this is not true. I _could_ probably implement the HTTP protocol over a simple serial port, point-to-point connection, without TCP... Ok, it would not make any more sense than hitting my own thumb with a hammer, but still...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but they have to listen on different port.

Please update your question if your still have problems.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer !